# Where can I find the unitartu-theme package?

Tags: packages, themes, posters

I am making a poster with latex and found a template on Overleaf that I like a lot. It is the UTartuCS Poster Template, linked to [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/utartucs-poster-template-landscape/qfpryjrdfxrb). it uses a package, unitaru-theme, which MikTex isn't able to find for me and that I can't find myself. I've searched the University of Taru website and CTAN, but it's not availible from those places. Does anyone happen to have it, or know where I can get it from?

Comment: you can simply download your overleaf project and use it locally

Comment: from your `here` link click on `open as template` then overleaf opens a project that includes uniartu-theme.sty then you can download the project from the project menu at the top left

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't used Overleaf before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download your overleaf project and use it locally

From your here link click on open as template then overleaf opens a project that includes uniartu-theme.sty then you can download the project from the project menu at the top left